# Form popup box button action link

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, popup

I have a PHP form and its action link is another PHP page which adds the data the user has entered into a database.

The other PHP page is looking for this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Previously I was having trouble displaying a popup before sending the PHP form to its action page once the sumbit/create button was clicked as the popup box never appeared once the button was clicked. That has now been resolved using the following on the button tag within the form (return false):

```
<button onclick="Alert.render('You are about to create a new group.'); return false" type="submit">Create</button>
```

Now the issue I'm faced with is that I'm not able to action link the button to the php page which will add the data the user has entered into a database.

my code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#dialogoverlay{
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    border-radius:7px; 
    width:550px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ background:#FFF; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #666; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#CCC; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ background:#333; padding:20px; color:#FFF; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{  }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot2{ }
</style>
<script>
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Are you sure?";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">Cancel</button>';
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot2').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok(); document.getElementById(\'contact\').submit();" name="submit">Continue</button>';
    }
    function createForm()
{
    Alert.render('You are about to create a new group.');
    return false;
}
    this.ok = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }


}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
</script>
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/form.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="redirect"></div>
  <div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  <header>
    <nav>
        <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div id="branding">
        <li><h1><span><a href="homepage.php">ProjectNet</a></span></li>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="homepage.php">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="findGroup.php">Find A Group</a></li>
                    <li><a href="groupForm.php">Create A Group</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Find New Members</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

            <div class="nav-login">
                <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                        echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                              <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                              </form>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST"> 
                              <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/Email">
                              <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                              <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
                              </form>
                              <a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>';
                    }
                ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="showcase1">
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="includes/form_process.php" method="POST">
    <h3>Creating a Group</h3>
    <h4>Please fill out the sections below.</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Project title" type="text" name="name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Description of the project...." type="text" name="message" ></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <button onclick="return createForm()" type="submit">Create</button>
    <!--name="submit"-->
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
</section>
      <footer>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="about1.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a>&copy; 2018 ProjectNet</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
      </footer>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form you have this:

```
<button onclick="Alert.render('You are about to create a new group.'); return false" type="submit">Create</button>
```

You're returning `false`, thus preventing from submitting the form, regardless of which option in modal was pressed. To solve this, add something like this:

```
document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot2').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok(); document.getElementById(\'contact\').submit();" name="submit">Continue</button>';
```

Notice this added part:

```
document.getElementById(\'contact\').submit();
```

It should submit the form for you.

---

Slight improvement:

Button code:

```
<button onclick="return createForm()" type="submit">Create</button>
```

And in JavaScript block add a new function:

```
function createForm()
{
    Alert.render('You are about to create a new group.');
    return false;
}
```

This will do the same thing but I think it's more eye-catching.

Comment: Thank you for the help, your method does seem promising, the only issue I have with taking the line of code that returns false out is that the popup box never appears when I click the submit/create button. Would you possibly have a solution for that?

Comment: @Hasan You'll have to return false on button because otherwise the form will be submitted. You may, however, change a little bit with a solution I added in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented the new improvements and now the popup box does not appear for some reason, I'm stuck on this problem lol. I think the form tags can be the reason for the popup box not functioning correctly? Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: @Hasan One more thing I had to edit. Those modal button have incorrect syntax. It should be on 1 line, not separated into 2 lines (e.g. `document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button 
 onclick="Alert.ok()">Cancel</button>';`)

Comment: Yeah on my IDE it's on one line, just that stackoverflows 4 space for code rule put it on a separate line :D

Comment: @Hasan Are you sure IDE has this on 1 line? Because even when I copied the code into notepad++, I had to remove some lines (or breaklines?). Other than that, it should be working... Or is there still something wrong?

Comment: Yes it's on 1 line, I've tried a load of troubleshooting but had no luck, I have no idea what could be causing the problem :(

Comment: @Hasan Your newly created function `createForm()` should not be in another function. Try to move right before `var Alert = new CustomAlert();` line

Comment: ohh alright, that fixed the popup box to reappear :) Do you have any ideas on what the issue can be with the problem of the "continue" button on the popup box not following through with the action link to another php page so I could add the data the user has entered into a database? Thank you so much for the continuous help dude!

Comment: How exactly it's `not following through with the action link to another php`? This seems to be a different issue now. But perhaps we can move to chat room since this discussion extended quite a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168003/discussion-between-edvin-tenovimas-and-hasan).